# Intermittently Access Violation Exception when calling the OpenCL function GetPlatformIDs via DLL call

Tags: c#, opencl, access-violation

I am writing an application in c# which uses OpenCL. I would like to access the functions directly rather then using an existing wrapper as I have done with other DLLs in the past. When I call the function GetPlatformIDs I intermittently get the following error:

```
AccessViolationException was unhandled

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I initially thought there was an error in my DLL call so I tried looking at other examples from other sites and code from open source projects but all of them behaved the same. If the code can get past the initial call everything else will work just fine, but 50% of the time it fails on that first call. To illustrate the problem I've created the follow bare-bones sample:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace openclerrortest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("OpenCL.dll", EntryPoint = "clGetPlatformIDs", ExactSpelling = true)]
        internal extern static unsafe int _GetPlatformIDs(uint num_entries, IntPtr* platforms, uint* num_platforms);

        static unsafe void Test()
        {
            uint numOfPlatforms;
            int ec = _GetPlatformIDs(0, (IntPtr*)IntPtr.Zero.ToPointer(), &numOfPlatforms);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace when it crashes:

```
at openclerrortest.Program._GetPlatformIDs(UInt32 num_entries, IntPtr* platforms, UInt32* num_platforms)
at openclerrortest.Program.Test() in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\openclerrortest\openclerrortest\Program.cs:line 14
at openclerrortest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\openclerrortest\openclerrortest\Program.cs:line 19
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `IntPtr*` is a pointer to an `IntPtr`. Surely you want `int**` instead?

Comment: The second parameter in the function is a pointer to an array of handles. The calling code allocates memory for the array and passes in the number of handles you have space for via the first parameter and the function fills the array and passes back the number of handles it actually wrote and an error code. If you request 0 handles it should just pass back the count and ignore the second parameter altogether.

Comment: Yes, I looked up the function documentation. I meant the automatic marshaling of `IntPtr` to `int*` might not be done for `IntPtr*` to `int**`. Why not use `int**` directly?

Comment: All 3 of open source projects (OpenCL.net, CLOO, and Scallion) I've been looking at as reference seem to want to keep them in IntPtr so that's what I was trying too.